# Py: Why elements from JSON repeat for every action?

Tags: python, json

I created a JSON file to pass my required data to a web page. Everything is working perfectly. But Whenever I refresh or repeat the action on the same file, JSON send double, triple and so on. I think I need to clear the JSON file whenever I enter into the coding for api action to pass JSON file. How can I do it on Python.

```
@app.route('/patient_cap')
def Patient_cap_mat():
   global numofCapability, MaxNumDis,capsArray,ListofPatCapability
   column_array=[]
   df2 = pd.read_csv('./datafiles/label_network.dat', sep='\s+', header=None)
   .       
   .// set of coding for required values
   .
   .
   for i in range(len(result_array)):
    eachpatient=CapabilityMat(result_array[i],df.loc[i].tolist())
    entry = {"patient":eachpatient.memid,
            "capability": eachpatient.capability}
    ListofPatCapability.append(entry)
JsonList = json.dumps(ListofPatCapability)
return JsonList
```

How can I clear the json object whenever we call api 'patient_cap'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListofPatCapability` keeps its value between calls because you declared it as a `global`, so you are seeing it grow because all of your results for each call are appended to it.

Does it really need to be global?  Do other parts of the program need to use it?

If not, take it out of the global section and just initialize it to be an empty list.

Comment: I am using ListofPatCapability in other part of the program too. Therefore I defined as global. Although Your answer seems reasonable, in my case, it should be global. Do you know any other solution.

Comment: If you want to clear it every time you call the function, just add `ListofPatCapability = []` after the `global` line.

Comment: Hey @John it's a great suggestion. Thank you.